# No error occurs but gd image does not get displayed

Tags: php, gd, captcha

I have written a piece of code to generate images from text in PHP using GD. When I run this code on my XAMPP localhost I do not get any errors but neither do I get an image.

Generate.php

```
<?php
    session_start() ;
    header ('Content-type: image/jpeg') ;
    $_SESSION['secure'] = rand(1000,9999) ;
    $text=$_SESSION['secure'] ;
    $font_size=30 ;
    $img_height=40 ;
    $img_width=100 ;
    $image=imagecreate($image_width,$image_height) ;
    imagecolorallocate($image,255,255,255) ;
    $text_color=imagecolorallocate($image,0,0,0) ;
    imagettftext($image,$font_size,0,15,30,$text_color,'captchafont.ttf',$text) ;
    imagejpeg($image) ;
?>
```

HTML

```
<img src="generate.php"/>
```

All I get when I run this HTML file on a localhost is image not found symbol in browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change this line:

```
$image=imagecreate($image_width,$image_height) ;
```

into

```
$image=imagecreate($img_width,$img_height) ;
```

because you have defined `$img_width` and `$img_height` variables and not `$image_width` and `$image_height`

You should also make sure that `captchafont.ttf` exists in the correct path and is used the correct way.  From manual:

> Depending on which version of the GD library PHP is using, when
>   fontfile does not begin with a leading / then .ttf will be appended to
>   the filename and the library will attempt to search for that filename
>   along a library-defined font path.

**Small advice for testing**

Comment/Remove line `header ('Content-type: image/jpeg') ;` and simple run in your browser this url for example `http://localhost/generate.php` to make sure no errors appear. Otherwise if this still doesn't add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the beginning of your file. After removing all errors and warnings, you should of course remove this line and uncomment line with `header` and then check if image is displayed correctly.

Comment: +1 for spotting it, but this kind of question should be closed as a typo, with maybe a comment explaining ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I've just added more explaination for this